# Retrieve data in AJAX based on condition

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying using AJAX to retrieve records which field: DATE is between when(variable contains a date) and until(variable contains a date). But it's not working.
If i give it a single condition it works --> `"Where" : "DATE < '"+until +"'"`

How can i fix what i'm doing to make it work?

```
$.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "Records?DB=EMP&Table=HISTORY",
                       dataType : 'xml',
                       data : {
                           "Where" : "'"+when +"' < DATE < '"+until +"'" 

                       },
```

Comment: @Satpal yes that's the condition i'm trying  to achieve? but the way you wrote it didn't work

Comment: Please specify with example what you want

Comment: @Satpal i have a  record with a field DATE: 20/10/2015
I want to retrieve  this record.
So based on a date range in AJAX:  20/09/2015 < 20/10/2015 < 20/11/2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use AND in between.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "Records?DB=EMP&Table=HISTORY",
     dataType : 'xml',
     data : {
         "Where" : "DATE BETWEEN '"+when +"' AND '"+until +"'" 
     },
```

Comment: didn't work, i'm getting ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: @mathieu_b, you have to add database details in your question. I think you are passing data in query.

Comment: @mathieu_b, you can try "Where": "DATE BETWEEN '"+when+" AND '" +until+ "'"

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your SQL query into a post request.
Better programming a REST server and send POST requests in JSON format.